# UITableView setContentOffset not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to get my UITableView to have an "overscroll" search bar. I have followed something pretty similar to [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view) and it basically works. Unfortunately if the uitableview doesn't have enough content to be scrollable, searchbar cannot be hidden once it is pulled down. Does anyone know how to make a searchbar in a uitableview be hidden by default(which this tutorial does do) and then be able to disappear again when the user "scrolls" down?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    ....
    [self hideSearchBar];
```

}
`-(void)hideSearchBar:{
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, searchBar.height];
}`
if dont work, say something.

Comment: That actually works initially. However once the user has revealed the searchbar, it then won't go away if I make the same call [self hideSearchBar] again.